# Minimizing leftover items in a 0/1 knapsack problem

Tags: knapsack-problems

I recently asked a question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77587572) and found that I need to solve a 0/1 knapsack problem. However, the problem has evolved to one where the knapsack problem is only part of it. The problem is as follows:

I have a variable named *num_items* which determines the number of items in the knapsack. Each item has a value of 1, and a *weight*. *num_items* also affects *weight* because each item has geometrical features (e.g. a circle's radius) which is [drawn from a normal distribution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.normal.html) where the number of samples is equal to *num_items*.

There are two goals:

1. Select the items that keep the knapsacks weight close to *target_range* (with a margin of error). This is a 0/1 knapsack problem addressed in [the SciPy manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/optimize.html#knapsack-problem-example) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77588932/7180705) to the aforementioned SE question.
2. To minimize *num_items*. The result of the 0/1 knapsack problem will naturally tell me to discard some items. Those items are part of the normal distribution and discarding them will add error to my modeling. I would like to minimize the number of discarded items which means finding the minimum *num_items*.

Is there an algorithm for the second goal? I think a brute force approach (trying all values for *num_items*) is possible, but would prefer a better solution.

Comment: What does num_items denote? Initially, you said that "num_items which determines the number of items in the knapsack"; then you said that "minimize the number of discarded items which means finding the minimum num_item"?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Both are correct. 
num_items refers to the size of the set of items involved in the knapsack problem which will have me discard some items.
I would like to find a value for num_items which minimizes the number of discarded items.